# Knack and creating a stopwatch

Tags: javascript

Knack lets you input JavaScript code, which I can input. However, how do I properly let the JavaScript code know where to go on the backend? I know to use the "view_" number, but what about $(document)(knack-submit) at the beginning, is that correct? I would appreciate any advice with using knack's JavaScript compatibility.

Comment: Knowing nothing about Knack, I can find their [documentation](https://www.knack.com/developer-documentation/#introduction) pretty easily. Looks like they have a lot of examples already there.